# Solving differential vector equations

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I have this problem:

A basketball is thrown from the top of a 50 m building horizontally at 30 ms−1. Find the kinetic energy of the basketball at t=1.8s

This is the code i wrote

```
m = 0.6;(*kg*)
sol0 = NDSolve[{m r''[t] == m {0, -9.81}, r[0] == {0, 50}, 
    r'[0] == {30, 0}}, r, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]
ke[t_] := 1/2 m r'[t].r'[t] /. sol0
ke[1.8]
```

I got the output of : 363.541

However the sample answer is saying that is wrong. Any ideas where i may have went wrong

Comment: I get the same answer. Further, a simple calculation 1/2 0.6 ( (1.8 9.81)^2 + 30^2)  gives the same answer as well. I think either the problem you are solving is different than the book, or the book answer is wrong.

Comment: hi, did you use a different code to get that answer. Yeah i think the sample might be wrong

Comment: The horizontal velocity stays constant. The vertical velocity v= g t = 9.81 1.8 =17.7 m/s^2 For the total energy from horizontal and vertical movement we need the mass: m. The energy is: 1/2 m ( vhor^2+ vvert^2 ) = 1/2 m ((9.81 1.8)^ + 30^2) = 605.9 m